# Yum, always install both 32 and 64 bit when available

Tags: yum

When using yum, is there a way to have both 32 and 64 bit packages installed whenever both are available?

I know I can specify *.i686 for individual packages... But I have a lot of errors that revolve around a missing 32bit package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In /etc/yum.conf add:

```
multilib_policy=all
```